# Google Resumable Upload

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage, chunks, video-upload, signed-url

I want to implement a google resumable upload for a video recording i am doing from my web app. I am fetching a signed url and initiating the resumable upload immediately when the first chunk is available. Here the issue I am facing is that the chunks will be available in the bucket only after i send my ***final chunk*** which ends with a ***200*** status. but my requirement is that each chunk will be immediately available so that my Backend can start some processing immediately as the first chunk is available. Can some help me in how to achieve this in my react app using google cloud storage?

Comment: What do you mean by "React app"?

Comment: That is not possible using resumable until the entire object has been uploaded.

Comment: thanks for the update, just want to know whether there is any way you are aware so that I can achieve a similar behaviour. My requirement is that my BE service should be able to start processing the video as soon as the first chunk (similar part) is uploaded so that the user will get the final video ready to watch in no time(or with as low latency) after he press the stop button

Comment: @EricMORAND i was just mentioning i am trying this from React application (my frontend service runs on react)

Comment: You can use [Composite object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects). ***Composite objects are useful for making appends to an existing object, as well as for recreating objects that you uploaded as multiple components in parallel.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a strong consistency in the item uploads to Google Cloud Storage. This implies that until the object has been fully uploaded and all chores related to Cloud Storage, including replication, is completed, it will not be visible. Until the upload is finished and your software/tool gets a success response, you cannot see or access an object.

It is already stated in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#introduction) that : ***Only a completed resumable upload appears in your bucket***. So you cannot access each chunk before uploads are completed.

Alternatively, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/@theyograjthakur/simplifying-large-file-uploads-with-react-and-node-js-a-step-by-step-guide-bd72967f57fe) which is using `react` as frontend and `node.js` as backend. You can use the resumable upload concept where Chunks are uploaded sequentially, enhancing stability. And In the Backend endpoint will receive and process file chunks sequentially using the `multer` package. Upon receiving the last chunk, it merges chunks into a complete file .

For your use case may be you can modify the code from the article accordingly to do required activity when first chunk is completed.